# Aggregating One-Sided Z Tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution

I have several observations of mean and variance for a variable $\theta$. I aim to do the following hypothesis test:

$H_0: \theta \ge 0$

$H_1: \theta < 0$

I can convert my observations of $\theta$ into z-scores. I can then take the sum of squares of these z-scores, which is $\chi^2(n-1)$. Using this approach ignores that the hypothesis is one-sided.

Do I, instead, take the precision weighted mean of $\theta$ and the sum of the precisions to aggregate my observations?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=aggregate+p-value for some options.